# Error code: HEALTH_CONSTRAINTS in Blue/Green Deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

I am working with Blue/Green Deployment using AWS CodeDeploy. The sample  deployment provided by AWS is working fine but when I am doing the same thing using custom Deployment, I am getting the following error:

The overall deployment failed because too many individual instances failed deployment, too few healthy instances are available for deployment, or some instances in your deployment group are experiencing problems. (Error code: HEALTH_CONSTRAINTS)

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You get this error when the overall deployment failed because too many individual instances failed deployment, too few healthy instances are available for deployment, or some instances in your deployment group are experiencing problems. You can check which lifecycle event failed for the instance and what is the error, also it would be helpful to log in to the failed instance and check the host agent logs.